# Simple List Items With Check marks

Tags: list, listitem, unordered

I am trying to build a list that has checkmarks next to the list items. So replace the text decoration with a png image of a checkmark. Currently I can't get the checkmark image to display. Here is the code:

```
<ul class="masterList">
  <li>Quickly organize small items and prep for dusting</li>
  <li>Quickly organize small items and prep for dusting</li>
  <li>Quickly organize small items and prep for dusting</li>
</ul>

.masterlist li::before
{
  background-image: url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Tick_Mark_Dark-128.png");
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 31px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 32px;
}
```

link to codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNMgea

Comment: your css has a typo, the L in masterlist ins't capitalized, but it is in the html

Comment: Good to note, it still isn't outputting though

Answer (score 0):

Start with this, and then add your other attributes:

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>Quickly organize small items and prep for dusting</li>
  <li>Quickly organize small items and prep for dusting</li>
  <li>Quickly organize small items and prep for dusting</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul
{
  list-style-image: url('http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Tick_Mark_Dark-128.png');
}
```

Comment: If you do it that way you don't have control over the positioning of the icon

Comment: Add it all back piece by piece as the issue was the way you were referencing the image

Comment: Here is an example of someone doing it with background-image: http://www.tidyhouse.ca/